# Como obter dados de duas tabelas em mesma coluna?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, entity-framework, linq

Tenho duas tabelas no banco de dados:

```
Tabela1
Id      Nome       Sexo
1       NomeA      Macho
2       NomeC      Fêmea
```

```
Tabela2
Id      Nome       Sexo
1       NomeB      Macho
2       NomeD      Fêmea
```

Gostaria de ter o seguinte resultado:

```
Id      Nome       Sexo       Tabela
1       NomeA      Macho      Tabela1
2       NomeB      Fêmea      Tabela2
1       NomeC      Macho      Tabela1
2       NomeD      Fêmea      Tabela2
```

Percebam que está em ordem alfabética das duas tabelas.

Como eu poderia fazer um **SELECT** no **SQL Server** que retornasse um resultado como este?

Usando **Linq** com **Entity Framework**, é possível fazer o mesmo? (Neste caso tem-se **db.Tabela1** e **db.Tabela2**)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Se as colunas são as mesmas, você pode usar um `SELECT` com `UNION` (se quiser evitar duplicações) ou `UNION ALL` se quiser exibir o resultado mesmo com as duplicações:

```
SELECT ID, NOME, SEXO, 'Tabela1' as TABELA
FROM TABELA1
ORDER BY NOME

UNION 

SELECT ID, NOME, SEXO, 'Tabela2' as TABELA
FROM TABELA2
ORDER BY NOME
```

No Entity Framework:

```
var uniao = db.Tabela1.Select(new {
    Id = Id,
    Nome = Nome,
    Sexo = Sexo,
    Tabela = 'Tabela1'
}).ToList().Union(db.Tabela2.Select(new {
    Id = Id,
    Nome = Nome,
    Sexo = Sexo,
    Tabela = 'Tabela2'
}).ToList()).OrderBy(x => x.Nome);
```

Comment: Muito obrigado @Cigano, mas como eu faria para colocar em ordem alfabética levando em conta as duas tabelas?

Comment: No final da _query_ tu precisa colocar um *order by*. Ex.: `... .ToList()).OrderBy(x => x.Nome);`

Comment: @Cigano, é necessário usar o `ToList()` duas vezes? Não seria melhor colocar só uma vez no final?

Comment: @JéfersonBueno Eu uso pra enumerar o resultado em memória e não depender do banco na hora de unir as coleções. Em teoria o desempenho é levemente superior.

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez Ah, entendo. Valeu pela resposta.

Comment: @JedaiasRodrigues Atualizei a resposta.

Answer (score 0):

Uma opção que teria é criar um View no SQL Server:

```
CREATE VIEW vw_Tabelas AS
  SELECT
      [Id]
    , [Nome]
    , [Sexo]
    , 'Tabela1' AS [Tabela]
  FROM
    Tabela1

  UNION

  SELECT
      [Id]
    , [Nome]
    , [Sexo]
    , 'Tabela2'
  FROM
    Tabela2
```

Assim, o seu query acaba sendo apenas assim:

```
SELECT [Id], [Nome], [Sexo], [Tabela] FROM vw_Tabelas ORDER BY [Nome]
```

E o LINQ igual:

```
var resultados = db.vw_Tabelas.Select().ToList().OrderBy(x => x.Nome);
```